Autodesk APS error Deprecated Service while calling the AuthenticateAsync() method from the Autodesk.Forge.TwoLeggedApi class
In our .NET Application we are creating the authentication token by calling the AuthenticateAsync() method from the Autodesk.Forge.TwoLeggedApi class. We are getting Deprecated Service error while calling this method. Please let us know if Any code change needed to fix this issue

It sounds like you might be using one of our old SDKs.
In that case simply upgrading to the latest version of it should solve the problem:
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/which-sdks-are-using-oauth-v2

Our application is written in .Net Framework 4.8 . We have used old Nuget packages that supports .Net Framework 4.8. Now I tried to upgrade the Autodesk.Forge.designautomation Nuget package to 5.1.2 . But we are getting an error that states that this Nuget package version is incompatible to .Net Framework 4.8. I have tried in .Net Framework 4.8.1. And getting the same error....can you please tell me that which version of .NetFramework will be support for oAuth v2.
